# Passing JSON list as input in MYSQL Sp

Tags: mysql, json

Is there anyway to pass JSON list to mysql stored procedure and insert in that sp?
It has to get the data from the list and insert as separate rows with individual columns.

Comment: Try [JSON_TABLE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a JSON field type, but it does not understand JSON. MySQL only understands SQL. When you input data into MySQL, it has to be in SQL.

You could use another language to interpret the JSON and convert it to SQL.